# Citrix session remote shadowing

Tags: citrix, shadowing

This is Citrix technology based question. I need to develop windows app which should have functionality of remote session shadowing. We have server on which XenApp server and XenApp SDK is installed, and we get session information from it by using PowerShell. Problem is that XenApp SDK does not provide shadowing functionality. Basically i need something like client to client session shadowing.

Is this possible at all?

Thank You!

Comment: If my answer was the one you were looking for you should accept it, else comment or clarify question pls

Answer (score 1):

You can shadow a session remotely using [WtsOpenServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383837%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [WtsStartRemoteControlSession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb394783%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) api, just like rds/terminal server sessions. You MUST however shadow FROM an Ica (Citrix) session.
For OS < Vista you can use WinStationShadow.

See also: http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2007/10/30/new-terminal-server-apis-in-vista-sp1/